# Vertically align vector arrows

Tags: vertical-alignment, arrows

I'd like to write an expression with several vectors:

```
$\vec{t} + \vec{a}$
```

I'd like the arrow to appear at the same level, but the `t` arrow appears higher than the `a` arrow. I tried with `\overrightarrow` but it's the same problem.

Comment: There was briefly a comment to thus effect, but it was deleted:  if you know how tall you want the arrows to be, something like `\vec{\vphantom t\smash{#1}}` should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also do the following to avoid having to change any of the existing mathematical code.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\let\nvec\vec
\def\vec#1{\nvec{\vphantom t\smash{#1}}}
\begin{document}
$\vec{t} + \vec{a}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

You will have to modify the `\def` command for the 'tallest'  variable used.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to do some `.aux`-file monkeying that will record every argument to which an `\alignedvec` is applied, calculate the tallest among them, and then use that on the next pass as the height of a strut (to replace the guessing / fiddling required for the `\vphantom`).

Comment: @LSpice I suspect it would be possible, but probably overkill.  If all the vectors are lower case then depending upon the font one of the letters `b, d, f, h, k, l, or t` would be the tallest if not the same height. (So `t` is a great general choice.  If you are using uppercase as vector then `I` would be a good choice for the tallest.

Comment: I personally ended up using `l` which is bit higher than `t` (I used only lowercase vector)

Answer (score 4):

Make a new macro for making vectors, say

```
\newcommand\myvec[1]{\vec{\vphantom{t}#1}}
```